# Is there any method to add some string to what found by regex in Android Studio?(ctrl+shift+R)

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

Basically, what I am trying to do is add ***double quote*** to the heads and tails of the numbers

```
String a = 1;
String b = 2;
String c = 3;
```

to

```
String a = "1";
String b = "2";
String c = "3";
```

So, I use **[1-9]** to find all numbers. Then, all of a sudden, it comes to me that I don't know how to get the values which regex found, like don't know what to set between double quotes.

Hence, I am wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **\d+** instead of **[1-9]** or at the very least **[0-9]+** to include the 0

The reason why you need the **+** is because your regex would not find 10 or any digits that has more than 1 digit. You can reference the groups that you have found by using **$1** (first group) **$2** (second group) and so on. So you could do "**$1**" as your substitution and (\d+) as your search although you might want to use a better regex ie:

```
=\s*(\d)+;
```

replace to

```
= "$1";
```

See https://regex101.com/r/SaT6nK/1

Comment: ya, thanks. I first use **[0-9]** and **$1** for substitution, but nothing happens. Cause i didn't add (), I should use **$0** for entire pattern or use  **$1** with () for first found.